# Wordpress How to display all posts in category, with specific tag posts at top

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to show the all Posts in the Category.
With the specific tag posts at the top.

For example:- 
I want to show all the Posts in the Category 'CAR'
Now, I want that when i Click On 'CAR' Category the Posts With Tag 'BMW' Displays Firsts. And All Posts Left in Category 'CAR' Shown After the 'BMW' Tag Posts.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom page template (PHP) and associate your CAR category page to that custom page template.

Then, you need to customize your custom page template query, including all the post in the CAR category, ordering the posts by TAG.

Please find here the main rules for creating the correct custom template/page query: [Official Wordpress Site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: I have no query like this one. You can find the necessary examples on the official link i posted.